# ¿Como podría hacer un truco para tener herencia múltiple en Java?

Tags: java

He buscado artículos sobre este punto, unos dicen usa interfaces, pero no se exactamente como hacer, tengo este problema :

```
Clase1 > method1 y por herencia tenga method 2 y 3
Clase2 > method2
Clase3 > method3
```

quiero extender Clase1 de Clase2 y Clase3
Algo como esto:

```
   public class Clase1 extends Clase2, Clase3 {


   }
```

Comment: Que tal!, te puedo decir que la herencia múltiple de esa forma, java no lo permite, para que lo entiendas mejor en el siguiente link te comparto este tema que ya ha sido tratado [¿Por qué la herencia múltiple no se admite en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104165/por-qu%c3%a9-la-herencia-m%c3%baltiple-no-se-admite-en-java?rq=1).

Comment: No hay trucos, solo te queda implementarlas como interfaces. Saludos.

Comment: Si lo sé pero me dijeron que hay trucos para hacer algo así pero no estoy seguro como se podría hacer

Comment: En efecto el truco es la implementación de interfaces, no hay más!

Comment: Yo quiero compartir mis métodos de ClaseB y clase C

Comment: @YSCGProJ ya respondieron gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien en Java no es permitido la herencia múltiple, tu puedes hacer un hack que algún vez yo hice. Según tu requerimiento:

```
  interface Clase1 {
      default void hacerLogica1() {
         //lógica 1 aquí 
      } 
  }

  interface Clase2 {
      default void hacerLogica2() {
         //lógica 2 aquí 
      } 
  } 

  class Clase3 implements Clase1, Clase2 {
        void metodo3() {
            hacerLogica1() ;
            hacerLogica2() ;
        } 
  }
```

Comment: duda, que no las interfaces se usan a través de la palabra reservada implements?

Comment: Impresionante, gracias esto me ayuda!

Comment: @shadow si, actualizado. Next no problem

Comment: Para tener en cuenta: la implementación de los métodos en una interface con `default` está disponible desde java 8

Comment: @Juan Java 7 está ya descatalocado, lo normal si está aprendiendo Java es que use la versión 8 o superior (a día de hoy la más reciente es la 11)

Comment: @PabloLozano no se recomienda trabajar con Java 11 por temas de licencia.

Comment: A menos que uses [OpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot), que sigue teniendo la licencia open source

Comment: @PabloLozano las versiones 9, 10, y 11 tienen menos de un año y medio de ser publicadas, coincido que la versión 8 sea la más ampliamente usada actualmente, y considerando esto mismo, no me pareció mal agregar el comentario. Y como aclaré es solo para tenerlo en cuenta: "Si copias el ejemplo y te da error de sintaxis, fijate la versión contra la que estás compilando."