# ¿Es correcta la herencia entre varias clases en Java?

Tags: java, poo, object, herencia, objeto

en clase me han dado una jerarquía de vehículos, sería así:

Primero, creo una clase padre llamada ***Vehiculo***.

```
public class Vehiculo{
//Metodos y propiedades de clase padre Vehiculo
.
.
.
}
```

Creo una clase hija de ***Vehiculo***, en este caso, ***Terrestre***:

```
public class Terrestre extends Vehiculo {
//Propiedades y metodos de clase Terrestre
.
.
.
}
```

Y ahora creo una clase hija de ***Terrestre*** llamada ***Coche*** (que sería clase nieta de ***Vehículo***):

```
public class Coche extends Terrestre{
//Propiedades y metodos de clase coche    
.
.
.
}
```

¿Es correcto realizar tal herencia? En caso de que no fuera correcto, ¿como implemento las propiedades de ***Vehiculo*** y ***Terrestre*** en ***Coche***?

Comment: [Creo que esto te puede servir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/104171/29967), de hecho, los ejemplos están basados en vehículos :).

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con es correcto? ¿Compila y hace lo que necesitas?

Comment: @A.Cedano sí, muchas gracias, lo he leído y ya me ha quedado claro. Una muy buena respuesta, gracias.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz me refería a si era correcto realizar una herencia de otra herencia, de otra herencia, etc. Todo funcionaba correctamente, pero me dijeron que era una chapuza hacerlo de esa manera y quería asegurarme.

Comment: Es correcto, tu único problema es que tu clase `Terrestre` debería llamarse `VehiculoTerrestre` ya que es un `Vehiculo` y si lo dejas así como lo tienes puede prestarse a confusiones.

Answer (score 1):

Tal herencia es correcta no hay errores logicos en lo que planteas... Pero si tu pregunta es como llamar a metodos tanto de ***Vehiculo*** como de ***Terrestre*** para tu coche pues me surgio la duda a mi tambien jaja pero he aqui tu respuesta...

Cuando dervias mas de una vez y utlizas el resultado de esas derivaciones en otra clase como tu ejemplo puedes llamar a cualqier metodo que esten contenidos en ambas de las q derivas llamando a **super** y el metodo que quieras ....Tan sencillo como eso...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]... Donde mensaje() es un metodo de ***Vehiculo*** y mensaje2() de ***Terrestre***.. Cualqier duda dejala en los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta depende mas de lo que vayas a hacer, o el programa que vayas a crear con la lógica del negocio que vayas a crear.

Para mi correcto seria, como super clase, la clase Vehículo, posteriormente en la jerarquía la siguiente clase seria Coche, y por ultimo seria terrestre, que recomiendo que llames a esa clase como CocheTerrestre para aclarar mejor. Esto queda de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Vehiculo{
//Metodos y propiedades de clase padre Vehiculo
.
.
.
}

public class Coche extends Vehiculo{
//Metodos y propiedades de clase padre Vehiculo
.
.
.
}

public class CocheTerrestre extends Coche{
//Metodos y propiedades de clase padre Vehiculo
.
.
.
}
```

Para llamar los métodos y atributos de la clase padre y abuelo, lo puedes hacer con this, también sirve para llamar métodos con sobre escritura. También puedes utilizar super para llamar métodos de las clases padres y abuelos pero llamarlos directamente, es decir, no llamar métodos sobrescritos en la clase donde estas.

Ahora, esta lógica la puedes mejorar. Puedes hacer que Terrestre Pertenezca a una clase padre llamada TipoVehiculo, la cual tiene sus comportamientos y atributos. Esto es porque un vehículo no solo va por un medio terrestre, sino por un medio aéreo, acuático, entre otros.

Para hacer esto, con el ejemplo anterior quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Vehiculo{
    public TipoVehiculo tipo;
    public Vehiculo(TipoVehiculo tipo){
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
 }

public class Coche extends Vehiculo{
    public Coche(TipoVehiculo tipo){
        super(tipo);
    }
}

public class TipoVehiculo{
    private String tipo;//GUARDA EL TIPO DE VEHICULO (Acuatico, Terrestre, Aereo)
    private int identificacion;//GUARDA NUMERO DEL TIPO
.
.
.
}
```

Es una forma de hacerlo, incluso, lo puedes ampliar mas con variables estáticas, para facilitar la programación, entre otras cosas. Pero lo que planteas en si esta bien, todo depende de la lógica y como hayas planteado el programa, y por supuesto, de lo que te pidan y quieras lograr.