# Problema estructural con POO (java)

Tags: java, poo, diseño-de-clases

como bien dice el título tengo un problema donde la solución mas lógica es heredar desde una Súper clase A a una Sub clase B, pero dada la naturaleza de ambas clases es imposible ya que Java no permite la herencia múltiple, y es un problema porque ambas clases ya heredan de la clase "JFrame" (son ventanas), en resumen el problema es el siguiente:

Todo empezó porque necesitaba heredar un dato de tipo DefaultListModel (para un JComboBox) desde una clase A a otras 2 clases B y C. El JComboBox de la clase A se iba a ir actualizando frecuentemente y en base a la herencia también se irían actualizando los datos de los JComboBox de las clases B y C (**el objetivo es que SIEMPRE compartan los mismos datos, o sea que se actualiza el JComboBox de la clase padre y se actualizan los JComboBox de las clases hijas**), lo cual se vería de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que la subclase B y la subclase C también heredan de JFrame y por ende Java no me deja heredar también de la Clase A:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en consecuencia mi "estrategia" para mantener los JComboBox actualizados a partir de una sola clase padre quedó truncada. Alguna idea?

Comment: En Java puedes tener una herencia múltiple de *implementación de tipos* mediante interfaces. Mira si [esta respuesta (ver punto **2** de la misma)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/104171/29967) puede ayudar en tu caso.

Comment: Por favor tu código como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Pero la superclase extiende JFrame, por lo tanto B y C al extender la superclase ya heredan JFrame, entonces  ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: @Aprendiz, lo tendré en mente la próxima vez que publique

Comment: @Sal, toda la razón, no me había dado cuenta de ese detalle jajajaj eso solucionó mi problema. Otra consulta, como puedo aceptar tu respuesta o votarla? creo que no me aparece la opción para hacerlo.

Comment: No puedes aceptar porque es un comentario, lo puse como respuesta y ahí podrás.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cómo bien comentas si la clase A hereda de JFrame entonces puedes ocupar la clase A cómo súper clase en las subclases B y C.

Ahora teniendo en cuenta esto, quedaría  como el siguiente código

```
public class A extends JFrame{...} // en esta clase ya se hereda las propiedades y métodos de JFrame

public class B extends A{...} // como A ya hereda de JFrame aquí puedes acceder a sus propiedades y métodos  y también las propiedades de A
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario heredar de una clase para poderla utilizar.

```
public miClaseA extends DefaultListModel {...}
public miClaseB extends miClaseA{
miClaseB(){
 JFrame miFrame=new JFrame();
 miFrame.setBounds(...);
 miFrame.SetDefaultCloseOperation(...);
 miFrame.add(miJPanel);
 miFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Tampoco es necesario heredar de una clase para acceder a alguna de sus propiedades, se puede acceder a ella a través de un método getter.

Además, es muy posible que estés utilizando mal la herencia. La herencia no se usa para ahorrar código de cualquier manera. y a cualquier precio. A veces es preferible ahorrar ese código a través de un método getter.

El truco para establecer bien una herencia es el truco de "ES SIEMPRE UN".

¿Un coche ES SIEMPRE UN animal? No. Entonces la clase coche no puede heredar de la clase animal. Aunque necesites heredar la propiedad o el método "velocidad máxima".

¿Un coche ES SIEMPRE UN vehículo?Si. Entonces puedes tener una clase vehículo de la que herede una clase coche.

¿Un JFrame ES SIEMPRE UN DefaultListModel? No. Entonces no puedes tener una clase que sea un JFrame que herede de un DefaultListModel. Si quieres acceder a alguna propiedad, deberás hacerlo a través de un método getter.

Y por último, que ese método sea estático o que necesite de instanciarse un objeto según si el método va a depender de al clase y ser estático o va a depender del objeto de esa clase y no ser estático.