# ¿Se puede guardar instancias de objetos en una variable en Java?

Tags: java, java-18

Tengo una variable `carro` que  se le debe asignar un valor. Digamos que cuando se inicie el programa me pregunte: opción 1 o opción 2 y dependiendo de la opción se instancie a la variable carro.

¿Se puede asignar instancias de objetos en una variable en Java?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué la herencia múltiple no se admite en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104165/por-qu%c3%a9-la-herencia-m%c3%baltiple-no-se-admite-en-java)

Comment: Si son del mismo tipo, no hay problema