# Extends mas de una clase

Tags: java

Hola quisiera saber de que manera se puede extender mas de una clase hija a la Clase Madre?
ej:
public abstract class Futbol extends Boca;River{

donde Boca y River serian otras clases

Comment: Revisa si las respuestas a [la otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104165/169744) te sirven. Sino edita la pregunta contando qué quieres lograr con la herencia múltiple y por qué no te sirven las otras respuestas y solicita su reapertura (en un día la solicitud puede ser aprobada). Se me ocurre que la pregunta pueda estar más orientada a cambiar el enfoque del código.

Answer (score 3):

En Java no se puede hacer herencia múltiple. Como lo indica @Alfabravo puedes acudir a [¿Por qué la herencia múltiple no se admite en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104165/por-qu%C3%A9-la-herencia-m%C3%BAltiple-no-se-admite-en-java) para entender por qué.

Sin embargo, es posible que tu inclinación por herencia múltiple en este caso se deba a una confusión sobre herencia en general.

Es incorrecto decir que Futbol extiende de Boca o de River, porque el concepto Futbol es un juego, pero Boca y River son equipos de Futbol.

Un Futbol no es un Boca, ni un River. Pero River es un Equipo de Futbol, y Boca es un Equipo de Futbol.

Por lo tanto, lo correcto sería crear una clase:

```
abstract class EquipoDeFutbol {
}
```

Y luego crear subclases:

```
class Boca extends EquipoDeFutbol {
}

class River extends EquipoDeFutbol {
}
```

Ahora Boca y River SON Equipos De Futbol.

Comment: no se porque me votan hacia abajo.. el comentario era valido.
Claramente esta confundido si quiere heredar Futbol de Boca y River.

Comment: Boca extiende de Futbol porque Boca es lo más grande que hay. Broma. Creo que una forma aproximada de herencia múltiple es la implementación de interfaces aunque no es lo mismo claramente. Y la verdad que Futbol extienda de Boca no tiene sentido y tampoco entiendo el voto negativo deberían justificarlo. Algunos tienen el dedo ligero con el voto negativo.

Comment: Si fuera ejemplos como F quiere heredar de B y R. Entonces se puede hablar en términos genéricos.

Pero si doy el ejemplo de Fruta que quiere heredar de Lechuga y Papa entonces el ejemplo mismo está mal planteado y merece una correción conceptual más grande.

Por eso fui en esa dirección.

Comment: Probablemente te votaron negativo porque la pregunta está duplicada y va a ser cerrada. En definitiva la respuesta se pierde. Una mejor forma de aportar es planteando una alternativa a las dadas en la pregunta que ya se hizo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104165/169744

Comment: Mala onda votar negativo por ayudarle a alguien. Tal vez la pregunta no tiene mucho valor para Stack Overflow (ya que no es muy general). Pero la respuesta si tiene valor para el que preguntó.

Comment: Lo de votar negativo no lo veo. Nunca voto negativo. Pero el autor de la pregunta puede editar la pregunta y solicitar su reapertura si ninguna respuesta le sirve.

Comment: La respuesta es 100% valida, la pregunta escondía un problema de lógica que no se aborda en el duplicado y por último la pregunta es duplicada/cerrada cuando se han emitido los 3 votos NO antes, antes es solo la opinión de un usuario, y por si fuera poco este motivo es aún menos valido en un usuario que no tiene privilegios para ver la votación. Yo dejo mi +1 para restaurar el orden en el universo

Comment: Yo te había votado negativo (ya no). La versión inicial de la respuesta no era una respuesta sino un comentario. Las preguntas malas, incompletas o escuetas (porque no había código ni explicación de la relación entre esas clases) no se responden (y tú explicaste desde tu visión del diseño, que no necesariamente es correcta, no sabemos!); se comentan para que las mejoren. EN los comentarios. Al final, bien podía ser un caso más de [problema XY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY) y por eso valía más llevar al OP a la explicación ya existente sobre herencia múltiple en la otra respuesta.