# ¿Qué significa polimorfismo en programación orientado a objetos?

Tags: java, poo, polimorfismo

Según mis apuntes (copiado textualmente), la definición es esta:

*"Polimorfismo: El polimorfismo es la capacidad de un objeto de tomar diferentes formas. En POO, el polimorfismo se refiere a la habilidad de una clase para tener diferentes implementaciones de un mismo método."*

---

**Aquí mi pregunta:** Si esto es así, entonces el polimorfismo no tiene que ver con la herencia herencia, porque la sobrecarga de métodos en sí sería un ejemplo de polimorfismo, ¿o me equivoco?.

Ejemplo de sobrecarga sin herencia:

```
public class Animal{

    public void sonido (){
        System.out.println("Grr...");
    }

    public void sonido (String sound){
        System.out.println(sound);
    }
}
```

Ya que si yo llamo a esa clase en un `main`, el método `sonido` tiene distintos comportamientos sin haber herencia.

Pero es que he estado buscando información y también se considera polimorfismo a la sobrescrita de un método de la clase padre en la clase hija, por lo que a esa definición no le veo mucho el sentido.

*Fuente: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bblFTvuk4pY*

No se si es porque entendí mal.

---

Por eso, pregunto: ¿El polimorfismo tiene que ver algo con la herencia, o no?.

¿Se consideraría polimorfismo a esto, porque el mismo método `sonido` cambia su funcionamiento al cambiar la instanciación del objeto "padre"? (Cosa que solo se puede hacer, según sé, de una clase padre, a una clase hija):

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClasePadre padre = new ClasePadre ();

       padre.sonido();

       padre = new ClaseHija();

       padre.sonido();

    }
}
```

¿Me podrías dar una definición precisa de polimorfismo en programación orientado a objetos?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! "sobrescritura de un método entre una clase hija y una clase padre" donde viste esto?? porque eso me suena a abstraccion, no polimorfismo...

Comment: Y la herencia no tiene mucho que ver con el polimorfismo... vamos con los animales.. el elefante hereda de la clase mamifero.. pero que tiene que ver el polimorfismo aca? hereda las propiedades y algunos metodos.. otros los puede sobreescribir.. pero en general, no tienen mucho que ver...

Comment: @gbianchi Pues entonces estoy un poco perdido. La definición la copié y la pegué de los apuntes que nos hace mi profesor de programación de FP. La abstracción la define así: "Abstracción: La abstracción es el proceso de enfocarse en los aspectos esenciales de un problema o situación y ignorar los detalles secundarios. En POO, la abstracción se utiliza para representar conceptos importantes de manera simple y clara."

Comment: pues... te esta dando una definicion correcta semanticamente... Existen las clases abstractas (en algunos lenguajes), interfaces (en otros lenguajes)... que son conceptos de POO, que especifican partes de POO.. Por ejemplo, la capacidad que tiene una clase de sobreescribir metodos de una clase padre.

Answer (score 1):

Para entender **`polimorfismo`** en programación orientado a objetos, se puede tomar como ejemplo tu clase `Animal`, la cual sería una superclase:

```
public class Animal {
  public void sonido() {
    System.out.println("Grr...");
  }
}
```

Creamos **dos clases distintas `Perro` y `Gato`, las cuales heredan de la superclase `Animal`, la cual tiene un método abstracto `sonido()`, en las clases `Perro` y `Gato` podemos implementar de forma distinta este método**, emulando los sonidos de estos animales.

```
public class Perro extends Animal {
  public void sonido() {
    System.out.println("Woof Woof!");
  }
}


public class Perro extends Animal {
  public void sonido() {
    System.out.println("Miau Miau...");
  }
}
```

[image: Jorgesys polimorfismo]

> "**Polimorfismo**: El polimorfismo es la capacidad de un objeto de tomar
> diferentes formas. En POO, el polimorfismo se refiere a la habilidad
> de una clase para tener diferentes implementaciones de un mismo
> método."

Esto es polimorfismo.

---

> ¿Se considera polimorfismo solo si son métodos que sobrescriben o
> sobrecargan a otros métodos de la clase padre, o no tiene por qué
> haber herencia?

Me parece que estas confundiendo un poco con Herencia, Herencia se define cuando una clase adquiere todas las propiedades y comportamientos de una clase principal. A partir de tu clase Animal, creamos una clase Perro que hereda de la superclase Animal, en nuestra clase Perro podemos crear otros métodos los cuales podemos implementar.

```
public class Animal {
  public void sonido() {
    System.out.println("Grr...");
  }
}

public class Perro extends Animal {
   public void comida() {
      System.out.println("comer carne!");
   }
   public void velocidad() {
      System.out.println("120 Km/hr");
   }
}
```

Cuando instanciamos la clase podemos implementar el método sonido, pero también otros métodos propios de la clase `Perro`:

```
class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Perro miPerro = new Perro();
      
      miPerro.sonido();
      miPerro.comida();
      miPerro.velocidad();

   }
}
```

Comment: Entonces Polimorfismo es... ¿Sobrescritura? Una cosa que me incomoda es lo siguiente: "El polimorfismo se refiere a la habilidad de **una clase** para tener diferentes implementaciones de un mismo método". Pero ¿ **Qué** clase tiene diferentes implementaciones de un método? ¿La clase padre? lo digo porque a la hora de llamar en el main al método de cada clase en especifico, solo vas a tener 1 opción, que es el método de la clase de la cual hayas instanciado el objeto.

Comment: ¿ Qué clase tiene diferentes implementaciones de un método ¿La clase padre?  así es, la clase Padre, pero en la Herencia además de poder implementar los métodos de la clase padre, puedes implementar los propios de la clase hija, revisa la actualización.

Comment: Creo que lo empiezo a entender. Solo para aclarar, entonces una clase (que no herede nada de ningún sitio) que tenga varios métodos en sobrecarga, estaría aplicando el concepto de polimorfismo, ¿no? ya que tiene diferentes formas, implementaciones... de un mismo método.

Comment: @Camy07 puede que confundas polimorfismo con sobrecarga?

Comment: No tiene absolutamente nada que ver polimorfismo con sobrecarga. Tú cuando usas sobrecarga de métodos ves que todos se llaman igual, puede que eso te confunda, pero si ves su FIRMA, es completamente diferente: `public void doThis(String);` es completamente diferente a `public void doThis(int);`. El código lo que ve es la FIRMA de los métodos, no su NOMBRE. Si dos métodos reciben un parámetro diferente, se consideran diferentes métodos aunque se llamen igual! De hecho, no puedes tener DOS FIRMAS iguales, jamás podrías tener `doThis(String a, String b);` y `doThis(String c, String d);` :)

Comment: @Camy07 Me parece que como menciona gbianchi, estas confundiendo polimorfismo y sobrecarga, revisa [sobrecarga de métodos en Java](http://profesores.fi-b.unam.mx/carlos/java/java_basico4_6.html#:~:text=La%20sobrecarga%20de%20m%C3%A9todos%20es,cu%C3%A1l%20definici%C3%B3n%20de%20m%C3%A9todo%20ejecutar.)

Comment: @Benito-B Muy bien visto lo de la firma ¡Muchas gracias por la aclaración ;)!

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes, el polimorfismo existe porque existe la herencia, sin herencia no hay polimorfismo, si tuviese que crear una definición, diría que es: "la variación del comportamiento de un método, dependiendo del objeto que lo invoque", no es perfecta, pero creo que te ayuda a entender.
El ejemplo que pones de la clase animal, es sobrecarga de métodos, osea, métodos que tienen el mismo nombre, pero que aceptan distintos parámetros.
Vamos con un buen ejemplo de polimorfismo.

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void emitirSonido();  
}

public class Perro {    
    @Overrive
    public void emitirSonido() {
        System.out.print( "guau" );
    } 
}

public class Gato {    
    @Overrive
    public void emitirSonido() {
        System.out.print( "miau" );
    } 
}
```

Como se puede ver, en la clase animal, declaré el método emitirSonido, como abstracto, ya que no tiene sentido que haga algo, porque no hay un sonido común a todos los animales.  Eso me obliga a declarar la clase abstracta.
Cada clase hija, implementa a su manera el método en cuestión.
A pesar de lo dicho, es válido, en la clase Animal, que emitirSonido no sea abstracto, sino que esté vacio:

```
public class Animal {
    public void emitirSonido() {

    }  
}
```

Y también es válido, que tenga una implementación (no lo recomiendo):

```
public class Animal {
    public void emitirSonido() {  
        System.out.print( "guau" );
    }
}
```

En cuyo caso implementaríamos las clases hijas de la siguiente manera:

```
public abstract class Perro {    
    // la magia de la herencia.
}

public class Gato {    
    @Overrive
    public void emitirSonido() {
        System.out.print( "miau" );
    } 
}
```

Yo uso crear métodos vacíos, ya que de esta manera, puedo instanciar objetos de la clase Animal (si Animal es abstracta, no se puede).

```
Animal animales[] = new Animal[ 2 ];
animales[ 0 ] = new Perro( .... );
animales[ 1 ] = new Gato( .... );
```

Para pedir los datos genéricos uso:

```
String color = animales[ x ].getColor();
int edad = animales[ x ].getEdad();
String color = animales[ x ].getNombre();
```

Y para pedir un dato específico o realizar una acción específica uso:

```
((Perro) animales[ x ]).emitirSonido();
```

Answer (score 1):

Veamos. Herencia y Polimorfismo son características distintas dentro de la POO como bien dices.

Te recomiendo [este](https://www.luaces-novo.es/polimorfismo-en-java/)  y [este](https://blog.hubspot.es/website/polimorfismo-java) artículos. Te ayudarán a tener una idea clara de que es herencia y polimorfismo y cuáles son sus variantes y diferencias.

En resumen:

- Herencia en POO es la capacidad de definir clases nuevas como *hijas* de otras. En este caso, las hijas pueden utilizar; es decir, **heredan** las propiedades y métodos de la clase padre. **No implica que exista polimorfismo**.
- Polimorfismo es la **capacidad de un objeto para hacer cosas distintas con dos o más métodos que tiene el mismo nombre**.
  **Puede existir sin herencia**
- De ambas, herencia y polimorfismo, hay varios tipos y no todos los lenguajes incorporan todos los tipos ni de la misma manera. Por ejemplo, JAVA [no permite la herencia múltiple de implementación de clases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104165/por-qu%C3%A9-la-herencia-m%C3%BAltiple-no-se-admite-en-java) (ver [esto](http://diccionario.sensagent.com/Problema%20del%20diamante/es-es/#:%7E:text=En%20los%20lenguajes%20de%20programaci%C3%B3n%20orientada%20a%20objetos%2C,%C2%BFpor%20qu%C3%A9%20clase%20lo%20hereda%2C%20B%20o%20C%3F) al respecto de la herencia múltiple) pero si la de *interfaces*.
- Respecto al polimorfismo, en el caso de JAVA tenemos:

  - Polimorfismo de asignación.
  - Polimorfismo puro.
  - Sobrecarga, estático o *de compilación*.
  - Polimorfismo de inclusión.
- Aunque otros simplemente distinguen entre **polimorfismo estático** o de compilación y **polimorfismo dinámico** o de ejecución; según cuando sea necesario y/o se aplique.

En tu ejemplo de la clase Animal utilizas la **sobrecarga**, que es una forma de polimorfismo pero, como comentaba antes, hay más.

Si lo aplicamos a tu ejemplo, en la clase padre tendríamos

```
public abstract class Animal {

  ...

  public abstract void emiteSonido();
}
```

y en cada una de las hijas...

```
public void class Perro extends Animal {

  ...

  @Overrride
  public emiteSonido() {
     System.out.println("Guau Guau");
  }
}

public void class Gato extends Animal {

  ...

  @Overrride
  public emiteSonido() {
     System.out.println("Miiaauuuuu");
  }
}
```

Fíjate que hemos definido la clase `Animal` como abstracta por lo que no se puede crear un nuevo objeto de esa clase directamente; es decir, la sentencia

```
Animal otroAnimal = new Animal();
```

provocará un error. Por tanto, para crear un nuevo animal deberás crear una clase que *extienda* -herede- desde la clase `Animal`. Ahora, en cada clase *extendida* desde `Animal` tienes que definir cómo se va a comportar el método *emiteSonido*. Esto si sería polimorfismo: el mismo método `emiteSonido` se comporta de manera distinta según la clase que se haya instanciado.

Desde el punto de vista del polimorfismo en POO, nos quedaría por hablar de los *interface* -interfaces para los amigos :-) pero eso es otra historia.

Espero haber aclarado tus dudas al respecto de lo que es polimorfismo y como esto no es lo mismo que herencia.

Que tengas un buen día.

Comment: Bienvenido, no puedes mencionar a otras personas en una publicación de la misma manera que lo puedes hacer en los comentarios. Tampoco es necesario ya que cuando públicas una respuesta le llega una notificación a OP.

Comment: Eliminada. Gracias por tu comentario. No lo sabía

Answer (score 0):

No es exactamente así. Los lenguajes no tienen la obligación de seguir una definición de diccionario. Lo correcto es tomar la definición [de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), más específicamente:

> Subclasses of a class can define their own unique behaviors and yet share some of the same functionality of the parent class.

En español:

> Las subclases de una clase pueden definir su propios comportamientos únicos y aún compartir la misma funcionalidad de la clase padre.

Para mí queda claro que se refiere a *sobreescribir* métodos exactos y no a crear una mera *sobrecarga* adicional.

De hecho, en Java existe la anotación `@Override` para que el compilador valide la sobreescritura de una función. Hay [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156432/169744) con respuestas al respecto.