# ¿En qué difieren las jerarquías de herencia diseñadas para heredar la interfaz, de las jerarquías diseñadas para heredar la implementación?

Tags: java, interface, polimorfismo, interfaz

"Una subclase puede heredar la interfaz o implementación de una superclase. ¿En qué difieren las jerarquías de herencia diseñadas para heredar la interfaz, de las jerarquías diseñadas para heredar la implementación? "
Es una pregunta que se encuentra en la sección de ejercicios sobre Polimorfismo en el libro "Cómo programar en Java" de Deitel edición 7. No puedo dar con una respuesta (ni siquiera creo entender bien la pregunta) cualquier ayuda me vendría genial; gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué la herencia múltiple no se admite en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104165/por-qu%c3%a9-la-herencia-m%c3%baltiple-no-se-admite-en-java)